# View not found when replacing a Fragment

Tags: android, fragment, android-support-library

I have an Activity that uses fragments. on certain actions i replace the visible Fragment. That works quite well, except one user reports an error on his droid photon.

Here is the stack trace:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No view found for id 0x7f060091 (com.b2.livewants:id/user_profile_fragment) for fragment UserProfileInfoFragment{40b3a8c0 #2 id=0x7f060091}
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:903)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1088)
at android.support.v4.app.BackStackRecord.run(BackStackRecord.java:682)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:1444)
at android.support.v4.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:429)
at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:587)
at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:130)
at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3844)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

And this is the function in question:

```
private void setFragment(Fragment fr){
    getFragmentManager()
        .beginTransaction()
        .replace(R.id.user_profile_fragment, fr)
        .commit();
}
```

**Edit:**

Here is the (shortened) layout file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    ...

    <FrameLayout
            android:id="@+id/user_profile_fragment"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="match_parent" />
</LinearLayout>
```

How is that possible? Android seems to have problems to find the view in that case... Does anyone had that problem before or has a tip for me?

Thanks
Simon

Comment: post your fragment class code

Comment: You might want to check and make sure that all your layouts have that view.  Could be you have a rarely used one in a different configuration dir that very few phones use.

Comment: there is just one layout file for the activity, everything else gets handled in fragments, which are inserted at user_profile_fragment as seen above.

Comment: How did you manage to overcome the issue?